# Fluent Nhibernate & SQLite mapping component

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a component on an entity that may be null. This works in a unit test with an InMemory database, but does not work on a file based SQLite database.
I use a boolean flag to indicate whether the component was set, but this seems to be a hack.

Is this a NHibernate or a SQLite Bug? Or am i missing something?

Here are my mappings stripped of business value:

```
public sealed class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
   public EntityMap()
   {
     Not.LazyLoad();
     Id(m => m.Uid);
     Map(m => m.HasComponent).Not.Nullable();
     Component(m => m.Component).ColumnPrefix("Component");
   }
}

public sealed class MyComponentMap : ComponentMap<MyComponent>
{
   public MyComponentMap()
   {
     Map(c => c.SomeBasicProperty).Nullable();
     HasMany(c => c.ListOfValues).AsList(li => li.Column("Number"))
                           .Component(part => 
                                         {
                                             part.Map(s => s.Name);
                                             part.Map(s => s.Value);
                                         }
                            .Table("ComponentValues")
                            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Not.LazyLoad();

   }
}
```

With the memory database the component on the entity is null when all columns for it are null. This is what i expect.
When using a file based database the component is empty. So i cannot use `entity.Component==null` to check if the Component has already been set.

Comment: can you post the unit test to see what you expect and what you get.

Comment: I´ll see to it. The problem is the unit test works, but only if using the memory database of sqlite.

Comment: what is the outcome when it works: the component is null, not null? what does happen if it doesnt work: the component is null, not null, exception?

Comment: Edited my question to describe the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested your code with inmemory and it returns `Component != null` for an inmemory database as expected. In NHibernate a collection is never null but can be empty and a component is only null if all properties are null hence the component should never be null. i guess that you tested like

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    id = session.Save(new Entity());
    tx.Commit();
}

var entity = session.Get<Entity>(id);
Console.WriteLine(entity.Component == null);
```

Get returns the same instance which has Component set to null.

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    id = session.Save(new Entity());
    tx.Commit();
}

session.Clear();

var entity = session.Get<Entity>(id);
Console.WriteLine(entity.Component == null);
```

Get returns the loaded instance which has Component set to non-null.

Comment: Thought about the collection being the cause, but did not realize that my test could be faulted! Still i would prefer proper null handling if the collection is empty...

Comment: not easyly doable because NH assumes the collection could be lazyloaded (where the size is not known until initialization) and defaults to this design. Either use the property getter to return null if Component and its collection is empty or hack/bend NH to do what you want